# Google Tag Manager: Trigger for session-time or number of pages visited

Tags: google-tag-manager

I want to fire a tag once a user is more than 5 minutes on my site (not the page, but the full site). Alternatively, fire a tag when the user has visited 10 pages in a row on my site.

How can I achieve that?

The timer trigger is only related to time on that page.

Answer (score 0):

### Page view > 9

One easy way for you to count pages would be to create a session variable and increment it Everytime a user visits a new page.

Once you create the session cookie, you can use it a a custom variable and trigger the custom event when a user visits more than 9 pages.

If you have a single page application this might be a bit more tricky but still doable.

### Session Duration 3+ mins

Similarly to the page count, you could create a session variable that has the exact time a page is loaded. You could then compare it to the session_start() API that is captured once a user's session begins.

Once you have both values, you could create a custom JS variable that calculated the difference and pass that to GTM. Then you can fire an event when it is greater than X minutes (probably will default to seconds or millisecond).